# Rename the taxonomy menu in drupal 7

Tags: routes, taxonomy-terms

I have taxonomy menu as the menu in my page.Here when i edit the taxonomy menu it is not getting updated in my menu.Can anyone help menu to fix this issue.

For example let say I have taxonomy menu item hello.Now i go to `structure-->taxonomy-->Home page menu--->list` links and I edited the hello to test.When I come to my home page it still showing the hello and it is not getting updated.

Answer (score 1):

When you edit your vocabulary, on "Structure > Taxonomy > Home page menu > Edit" there should be a "Select to rebuild the menu on submit" checkbox.  This helped in my case.

Because the following warning, you should consider making a backup before doing this.

> This will delete then re-create all of the menu items. Only use this option if you are experiencing issues like missing menu items or other inconsistencies.

Comment: There is any way to rebuild the menu automatically.If i do the "Select to rebulid the menu on submit",the id of the menus are getting changed.I need the same id even when the taxonomy menu is get edited.

Comment: Here when i select the "Select to rebuild the menu on submit." it delete and recreate all the menu.But I want only menu get upadate if there is any change

Comment: Thats bad - in this case you could use the module Menu Names CSS http://drupal.org/project/menu_css_names. This module adds the target path of a menu item as a sanitized css-class to the li-item, to which you can refer in your stylesheet.